# Reset gun to left or right when player stops shooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So this code is meant to rotate the gun to the mouse position whilst the shoot button is held then resets to facing left or right depending on when the shoot button is released. But I think there's a problem with my `ResetGunRotation()` at the end because although the gun stops rotating when the player stops shooting, it still flips left or right depending on the mouse position, how can I fix this?

```
void Start()
{
    mainCam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    mousePos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (InputSystem.Shoot() && canShoot)
    {
        canShoot = false;
        Shoot();
        isShooting = true;
    }

    if (!canShoot)
    {
        UpdateGunRotation();
    }

    if (!InputSystem.Shoot() && canShoot)
    {
        isShooting = false;
        ResetGunRotation();
    }

    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer >= timeBetweenFiring)
    {
        canShoot = true;
        timer = 0;
    }
}

void UpdateGunRotation()
{
    Vector3 rotation = mousePos - transform.position;
    float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(rotation.y, rotation.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);

    if (mousePos.x > transform.position.x)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, 180f, transform.rotation.z);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, 0f, transform.rotation.z);
    }

    float gunangle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y - transform.position.y, mousePos.x - transform.position.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    if (mousePos.x < transform.position.x)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(180f, 0f, -gunangle));
    }
    else
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, gunangle));
    }
}

void Shoot()
{
    Instantiate(bullet, bulletSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
}

void ResetGunRotation()
{
    if ((mousePos.x > transform.position.x) && (isShooting = true))
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));
        isShooting = false;
    }
    if ((mousePos.x < transform.position.x) && (isShooting = true))
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f));
        isShooting = false;
    }
}
```

I tried several kinds of bools including canShoot, isShooting, wasShooting to make sure that the gun stops tracking when I stop shooting, but maybe a bool isn't the way to go because it's such a small window of time

Comment: Im assuming `isShooting = true` is supposed to be `isShooting == true`